# Is it possible for a class to have a data member that only exists within an instance of that class if it isn't null?

Tags: java, dropwizard, lombok

This code is in Java and utilizes Dropwizard and Lombok. I am wondering if there is an annotation I can use or some other way to make a data member of a class exist if it has some non-null value OR not exist if the value is null.
I'm not sure if this is something that is possible or not, but I'm trying to work within some restraints.

The relevant VerificationResponse class is this:

```
private SomeResponseContext context;

public static VerificationResponse response(String responseCode, String responseType, 
        String explanationCode, String explanation, String optionalField) {

    SomeResponseContext context = VerificationResponseContext.builder().responseCode(responseCode).
            responseType(responseType).explanationCode(explanationCode).explanation(explanation).optionalField(optionalField).build();

    VerificationResponse verifyResponse = VerificationResponse.builder().context(context).build();

    return verifyResponse;

}
```

The someResponseContext class looks like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder(builderClassName="SomeResponseContextBuilder") 
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@ ? //Don't include optionalField if it is null
public class SomeResponseContext {
        private String responseCode;
        private String responseType;
        private String explanationCode;
        private String explanation;
        private String optionalField;
}
```

When I return the VerificationResponse verifyResponse I want its SomeResponseContext member to either have all the fields like the SomeResponseContext code posted above or, if when SomeResponseContext is built if the value of the Sting optionalField is null/does not exist then that data member is dropped and the class for all practical purposes would look like this:

```
public class SomeResponseContext {
        private String responseCode;
        private String responseType;
        private String explanationCode;
        private String explanation;
}
```

The issue is that certain situations expect verifyReponse to only have the four data members and it will crash if there are more. However, another situation has arose where we need a fifth data member in certain situations.

Comment: Abstract class with the minimum level of fields should work for you

Comment: Yeah I think that solution could work...I was just thinking there might be a magic lombok annotation or something like that.

Comment: I think it is not possible. It would require to have one type with 2 different class structures. I will post it as answer later.

Comment: Are you concerned about the JSON representation of the response? If so you could use @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)

Comment: Yes Matt, I just stumbled upon @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL). With this, the field wouldn't be included in the response when I'm building the response ... .entity(verifyResponse).build(); ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible that would require the JVM to load a type/class
with two different structures:

```
class foo{
    String s1;
}

class foo{
    String s1;
    String s2;
}
```

Which one to use? It is ambiguous. Your best shot if the extra field becomes expensive over time is to use an abstract class

```
abstract class foo{
    protected String s1;
}

class foo1 extends foo{
}

class foo2 extends foo{
    String s2;
}
```

Lombok should be able to pick those up